# Ubuntu Server 15.04 command not found rvm-prompt в ZSH?

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, zsh

При выполнении некоторых команд, например:

```
$ /etc/cron.daily/prelink
```

Выдается ошибка

```
zsh: command not found: rvm-prompt
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: решить просто: не запускать программы, не предназначенные для такого запуска.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот это помогло решить проблему

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm install 2.2.2
rvm use 2.2.2 --default
ruby -v
```